# How to take backup of azure SQL-Managed Instance backup to azure blob

Tags: t-sql, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-managed-instance

I am having a SQL-Managed Instance database now I wanted to take backup in .bak format to blob storage. The current Command I am using is

```
WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE'
, SECRET = 'Pasted my sas token generated from azure portal blob storage'
go

BACKUP DATABASE [DB_Name]
TO URL = 'blob url/cointainer name/testing.bak'with checksum;
```

But by this I am getting a error:
"BACKUP DATABASE failed. SQL Database Managed Instance supports only COPY_ONLY full database backups which are initiated by user."

I have also tried to give "**COPY_ONLY**" instead of checksum but then again I am facing a error:
"Msg 41922, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
The backup operation for a database with service-managed transparent data encryption is not supported on SQL Database Managed Instance.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
"

**Note:** I have a database of approx size 800GB

Answer (score 2):

To prevent the original error message and you are comfortable with the increased security risks you can remove encryption:

Alter database [database_name] set encryption Off

use [database_name]

DROP DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY

Answer (score 1):

The backup command should be:

```
USE [master]

BACKUP DATABASE [SQLTestDB] 
TO  URL = N'https://msftutorialstorage.blob.core.windows.net/sql-backup/sqltestdb_backup_2020_01_01_000001.bak' 
WITH  COPY_ONLY, CHECKSUM
GO
```

You could follow this Azure tutorial:
[Quickstart: SQL backup and restore to Azure Blob storage service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tutorial-sql-server-backup-and-restore-to-azure-blob-storage-service?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=tsql):

[image]

It will help you backup the database(.bak) to Blob Storage step by step:

1. [Create credential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tutorial-sql-server-backup-and-restore-to-azure-blob-storage-service?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=tsql#create-credential)
2. [Back up database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tutorial-sql-server-backup-and-restore-to-azure-blob-storage-service?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=tsql#back-up-database)

Hope this helps

Comment: It gives me a error
"Msg 41922, Level 16, State 1, Line 46
The backup operation for a database with service-managed transparent data encryption is not supported on SQL Database Managed Instance.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 46
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
"

Comment: Indeed! there is no easy way out here: encryption must be disabled (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54325238/3518693)

Answer (score 1):

Error is related to [service managed TDE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/transparent-data-encryption-azure-sql?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=azure-portal) encryption since all database by default encrypted and service managed TDE does not allow to take copy_only backups. You need to either [disable service managed TDE](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-database/take-a-copy-only-backup-of-tde-protected-database-on-azure-sql/ba-p/643407) or [Enable TDE with customer managed keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/transparent-data-encryption-byok-azure-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to take backups.
Since your database size is 800 GB and if BackupSize > 200 GB then split your backups to multiple files. This is a [limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/sql-server-backup-to-url?view=sql-server-ver15#limitations) with blockblob.

Comment: What if I have to store in Page blob

Comment: You can't actually access it since you are only allowed to create credential using SAS token